# Solution Structure sol=ode45 has different number of time steps compared to [t,y]=ode45

Tags: matlab, ode45

As a beginner in Matlab I am exploring the ode45 function with test.m containing the ode equation to be solved.

In an editor I call this function separatey via 2 options. In one case I have the defined
Option 1

```
t=[0 50];
y0=[0 2];
[t,y]=ode45(@(t,y)test(t,y),t,y0);
```

and in option 2 I ask for a structure output

```
t=[0 50];
y0=[0 2];
sol=ode45(@(t,y)test(t,y),t,y0);
```

However, the resulting time steps are less for the structure option 2 compared to option 1 and so my plots are "coarser".

I could not find a way to increase the number of steps to refine the solution for option 2....Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `deval` function with `sol` and your chosen time points. For example,

```
tSpan = 0:0.01:50;
y = deval(sol, tSpan);
plot(tSpan,y)
```

See [Evaluate and Extend Solution Structure](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#bu3ujz9) in the documentation